# connect to google datastore from Python

Tags: python, export, google-cloud-datastore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PyDev project for Google App Engine not finding webapp2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756981/pydev-project-for-google-app-engine-not-finding-webapp2)

I am doing the helloworld tutorial and cannot connect from Python;

This is the app.yaml file:

```
application: "ceemee11111"
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:


- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.app

builtins:
- remote_api: on
```

This is start of helloworld.py:

```
import cgi
import datetime
import urllib
import webapp2

from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api import users


class Greeting(db.Model):
      """Models an individual Guestbook entry with an author, content, and date."""
      author = db.StringProperty()
      content = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
      date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

in Python shell I chdir to helloworld
import helloworld

and get import error "No module named webapp2"

The app runs in localhost and also in ceemee11111.appspot.com without error.
As a test I commented out "import webapp2" and tried again and got an error
"No module named google.appengine.ext"

Please some ideas

Dan

applicaton

Answer (score 1):

It seems that python can't find the library, so

- Have you webapp2 installed in the system?. You can try with "pip install webapp2" or "easy_install"
- If they are still missing, maybe you should check your "PYTHONPATH" variable, to check where is python looking for the libraries, and add yours to the path.

Comment: I would think if the app works on localhost and appspot.com that the modules would available. webapp2 is not in the available modules for python so I am going to try and install it.

Comment: I have installed webapp2 in the modules of python and run the import helloworld again and get "import error: no module named webob"

Comment: This seems very complex for a basic process. All I need is to have put() and fetch() access to the google datastore to get and retrieve data. Is there an easier method to do this.

Comment: OK this is starting to make sense. google has its own /lib of modules and python has its /lib of modules. I have installed pip, can I go to the google/lib and run     $ pip freeze -E [env1] > requirements.txt and then go to the python/lib and run   $ pip install -E [env2] -r /path/to/requirements.txt and if so what is the   /path/to/requirtments.txt

Comment: Another trick to make google_appengine available to the system (i had to do it to use nosetests --with-gae) y to make a link in /usr/local to your google_appengine directory. Maybe thats not so complex.

Comment: all i had to do was add c:\....\google_appengine to the path variable to use the google lib instead of the python lib